# Is it possible to share a variable between few threads but not all of them?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, thread-safety

I am pulling data from 3rd party API and I was wondering if it is possible to share variables between some threads, but not all of them.

Example:

I have 2 users and I'm starting 2 threads for each user. Lets say threads A,B for user 1 and threads C,D for user 2. Now I need some sort of flag to inform threads when to stop (lets say total number of pages that were already read, which varies from user to user). The problem is, the flag has to be synchronized for 2 threads that belong to this specific user, but not other threads. I cannot modify user entity. Creating 2 flags is out of option because this is just an example and in reality there might be multiple users pulling their data.

Is this possible? If yes, then how?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your *threads* for the user, also create the flag that needs to be shared and pass it to the *thread* so they can use it and share the information.

Something like:

```
AtomicBoolean userFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
Runnable a = new UserRunnable(userFlag);
Runnable b = new UserRunnable(userFlag);
// run a and b
```

And `UserRunnable`:

```
public class UserRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean flag;
    // + constructor

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // use the flag
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it will also work if I create an object holding 2 integers and access them using synchronized{} block inside a thread (in run method)? It will be synchronized only between the threads containing this particular reference to an object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just create and object with the boolean flag and pass it to the 2 threads of the same user in the constructor and store it in a field

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to share a variable between few threads but not all of them?

That depends on what you mean by "share".  All of the threads in a program run in the same virtual address space.  Any object in memory potentially can be accessed by any thread, but that doesn't mean that every thread *has* to access every object.

Threads do whatever the code that you write for them tells them to do.  If you want two different threads to look at two different flags, then write code for them that looks at two different flags.  Or, write a class that accepts a `Flag` object in its constructor, and then use the same class for both threads, but use different instances constructed with references to different `Flag` objects.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda new to multithreading and I somehow thought that if I declare an object inside a thread, then it gets synced with all threads, no matter the instance. Now I'm wondering why did I even think that way. Useful info tho. Thanks for your input.